# "Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist)." error when trying to log to GCP using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to have my Flutter app log to a specific google cloud project's log bucket instead of the developer console. I'm running into a `Permission 'logging.logEntries.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).` when I run the code. How can I fix this? The dart code for posting the log is below.

```
final logEntry = {
    "jsonPayload": {
      "message": {
        "test": "entry",
        "test 2": "entry 2",
      },
    },
    "logName": logName,
    "resource": {
      "type": "global",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": projectId,
      },
    }
  };

  final url = "https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/entries:write";

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    headers: {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      "X-goog-api-key": apiKey,
    },
    body: json.encode(
      {
        "entries": [logEntry],
      },
    ),
  );
```

The API key I created has no API restrictions, but I did also try restricting it to only use the logging API, but it still has the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `logging.logEntries.create` permission to the Service Account used by your `Flutter` app.

From the `IAM` page in `Google Cloud` console, you will be able to give a role containing the above permission to your Service Account.

The [logs writer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#logging.logWriter) role contains the required permissions.

Alternatively, if you used a custom role, you can also add directly the `logging.logEntries.create` permission to this custom role.

Comment: This fixed the error, I initially was using an API credential key and not a service account key. I'm now getting an `API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.` error. I'm using an API key created on a service account with a logging admin role.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write):

> The permission `logging.logEntries.create` is needed on each project,
> organization, billing account, or folder that is receiving new log
> entries, whether the resource is specified in logName or in an
> individual log entry.

So, you need to give the `logging.logEntries.create` permission to the Service Account used by your Flutter app.

You can also refer the detailed article on [Access control guide](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control).